# HTTML to PDF conversion using pypetter in aws lambda

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, html-to-pdf

am using python 3.7 as runtime and  pyppeteer along with dependencies for html to pdf conversion in lambda aws. The conversion is happening but styles are not getting as expected. attaching the html and pdf for reference[image]

Comment: It would help folks if you could share some code.